# Seek implementaion in random access file

Tags: java

I am trying to use RandomAccessFile for my use case. I just want to know whether `seek` will always count the file from the beginning.

```
  randomAccessFile.seek(100);
  randomAccessFile.seek(99);
  randomAccessFile.seek(98);
```

Does the above three operations count the bytes from the beginning and set the pointer? Or It just go back to one character from the current pointer?

I couldn't find the native implementation for this method.

Comment: Interesting question, because the `seek()` method is implemented via JNI and is platform specific.

Comment: @yshavit This may just be a conceptual figure, not necessarily that `seek` is _implemented_ this way.

Comment: @yshavit it may have some enhancements for corner cases. From that  point of view I am asking

Comment: Yes, he is asking whether the first call will go 100 forward, but the second call will go one step back

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks. Let's consider Linux platform which is mostly used

Comment: I don't think it really matters, and here's why: Files themselves can be fragmented on the storage medium (e.g. hard disk).  So even though you might think that navigating from 100, to 99, to 98 is "close," and therefore "fast," in practice the head of the hard disk could be going nuts.

Comment: I would guess that `seek()` doesn't physically do *anything*. I'm basing that on this part of the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)): *Setting the offset beyond the end of the file does not change the file length. The file length will change only by writing after the offset has been set beyond the end of the file.* So, calling `seek()` will very likely only set a memory value, and nothing physically happens until a read or write occurs. My guess, anyway.

Comment: @Andreas "It depends". Calling seek on a tape device, for example, may - if the device driver implements that - seek the tape to that position. And I would call that "something physical" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the above three operations count the bytes from the beginning and set the pointer?

No, they do not physically traverse all the bytes from the beginning of the file. That's the entire point of "Random Access", i.e. it'll jump straight to where you ask it to go.

Comment: "it'll jump straight to where you ask it to go" How is it implemented? Let's say I have 100 bytes. I seek to 52nd byte. How will it read from 52nd onwards? I don't get it. Thanks

Comment: @GopsAB Are you asking how low-level file I/O works for all operating systems? Sorry, too broad to answer, since that would require explaining physical and logical block sizes, OS native APIs for working with files, and searching thru Java native source code to figure out which exact methods Java uses on various systems. Just accept the fact that if you have a 100 Mb file and ask to start reading at offset 75,000,000, it will do so without having to scan thru 75,000,000 bytes, and be happy that smart people made that work for you.